# Good test runner for OCUnit/XCode Unit Tests

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocunit

Is there a good GUI based test runner for the OCUnit/XCode 4 unit testing frameworks? I'm looking for a redlight/greenlight type GUI, maybe something that looks like the NUnit test runner. I found [OCRunner](http://www.mcubedsw.com/dev/ocrunner), but it looks like it hasn't been maintained since 2009. It's unfortunate, because OCRunner looks like it was exactly what I was searching for. It loads on Lion, but I can't get it to pick up my test bundle and run it.

Any suggestions for an alternative or a way to get OCRunner to run on a unit test bundle against an iOS project?

**FYI - I'm running XCode 4 with the default unit testing bundle template*

Answer (score 0):

You should use [GHUnit](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit).
I've also managed it to run it automatically under Jenkins with the iOS Simulator. GHUnit can also export Jenkins valid XML's (JRun).